# How to programmatically find the PostgreSQL data directory?

Tags: postgresql, windows, command-line

I'm creating an installer for my program and I'd like to check if the database already exists in the computer. I do this by calling `psql -lqt | findstr dbname`. If someone knows a better way I`ll be glad to learn it.

Well, now I know if the database exists, but I would also like to know where its data directory is. Is there a programmatic way to find this out?

Comment: I sure hope you don't attempt to install your program in the Postgres data directory; that would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`show data_directory`

or

`select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory'`
but you can only do that as the superuser.

You can run that from `psql` or any SQL client. - [user1822](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)